# How to select count all and rows and only echo where column is not empty

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to count all rows and get a number of those that are not empty.

```
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];
$PQR = (!empty($row['position'])) ? $numrows : '';  
echo $PQR;
```

Comment: what is `$row`? Where it is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about getting only the ones, you need?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads WHERE position IS NOT NULL or position != '';

$numrows = mysql_numrows( $result );
```